# Add attributes to graphs using igraph in r

Tags: r, igraph

I have a dataset of features in the form of a csv available at below link

https://github.com/pranavn91/PhD/blob/master/Expt/27022%20feat.csv

```
name    birthday    education   classes.from.id
27136   6971           NA              NA
27137   841            NA              NA
27138   841            NA              NA
27139   841            NA              NA
```

I have an adjacency matrix of a graph in the form of a csv available at below link

https://github.com/pranavn91/PhD/blob/master/Expt/27022.csv

```
       27139    27138   27136   27137
27139   0         1       1      1
27138   1         0       0      0
27136   1         0       0      1
27137   1         0       1      0
```

I want to convert adjacency matrix to graph and set the vertex attributes.
but when i check the birthday of first vertex of the graph, i get 841 i.e. value of the second node. Also in the edgelist the edges of first node are missing

```
library(igraph)
path <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/27022.csv"
dat <- read.csv(path, row.names=1, check.names=FALSE, header=T)
m = as.matrix(dat)
g = graph.adjacency(m,mode="undirected",weighted=NULL)


path2 <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pranavn91/PhD/master/Expt/27022%20feat.csv"

prop <- read.csv(path2,row.names=1, check.names=FALSE, header=T)
head(prop)


for (i in V(g)) {
    for (j in names(prop)) {
        g <- set.vertex.attribute(g, 
                                           j, 
                                           index = i, 
                                           prop[i + 1, j])
    }
}


igraph::degree(g,v=V(g))
###degrees of nodes in g are 27136 - 3,  27137 - 1, 27138 - 2, 27139 - 2
###actual as per adjacency matrix should be 27136 - 2,  27137 - 2, 27138 - 1, 27139 - 3
```

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
for (nm in names(attribs)) g <- set_vertex_attr(g, nm, value = attribs[[nm]])

V(g)$birthday
## [1] 6971  841 6971  841
```

Comment: did you check the degree of vertex 27022 ? as per adjacency matrix it has 215 edges but as per the graph object it has only 31 edges.

Comment: I used your example data, not the huge CSV file. Can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: My guess would be you may need `header=TRUE` in your first `read.csv` call.

Comment: csv are not big. but still i edited the question with MCVE